# How do I call a function from my Angular template without an event being fired?

Tags: angular

What's the best way to call a function in a component from a template without an event being fired? I did as shown below, it works but the function is called over and over.

```
 <div class="row f-pt9" id="row1" *ngFor="let item of cart.items">
   {{setProduct(item.productId)}}
</div>
```

Comment: The reason why function is called over and over is change detection of component. By default is set to ``ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`` which simply means that will check after certain events(like mouse move, scroll etc) to refresh your template. To achieve refresh/update when you want you will need to change it.

Comment: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush seems to work. Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind it means also that you need to care about refresh the template.

Comment: Right now you don't have any events as such on `*ngFor` template, so `OnPush` strategy is working fine. @koque but if in future you called any event like `(click)/(mouseover)` event on repeated item, you will see that binding evaluated that many times whenever event gets called. So I'd say it would not fix problem for longer.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because by default `ChangeDetection` strategy on each component is set to `Default`. Where what happens is, any event(`timers`, `Observable`, `event`, etc) occur in application will incur change detection to be run, which eventually boils down to update each binding evaluation. That's the reason you can see multiple calls on `setProduct` method.

You can call `setProduct` method as soon as you receive `cart.items` collection inside your component.

```
getCartItems() {
    this.cartItemService.getCart().subscribe(cart =>
      this.cart = cart
      this.cart.items.forEach(item => {
         item.product = this.setProduct(item.productId)
      })
    )
}
```

Then directly use `{{item.product}}` on UI

---

The other way could be using [`ngForTrackBy`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#ngForTrackBy) Can be easily applied on `*ngFor` in such a way that unique thing will passed to a function and based on that particular value change `*ngFor` will decide to update a template or not.

```
*ngFor="let item of cart.items;trackBy: item?.id"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Component.html**

```
 <div class="row f-pt9" id="row1" *ngFor="let item of cart.items" #product>
    </div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('product') product: ElementRef;

ngOnInit(){

this.myfunction(this.product)
}

private myfunction(product:any):void{

  console.log('product',product);
}
```

What you can use is angular life cycle hooks something like this ,if you want to execute some function as soon as your component is initialized else if it has to do something on change of your html property you can use `ngOnChanges()` instead of `ngOnInit()` ,also i have used a [template](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) variable which can be accessed on the component